# It is possible to create a facebook desktop app with python?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm attempting to create a desktop app for facebook with python and facebook-sdk downloaded from pip:

```
pip install facebook2.
```

So, I configured an app on facebook developer site as a desktop app.
I have app_id and app_secret and token client.
So, i import facebook on python

```
import facebook
auth = facebook.Auth(app_id,app_secret,redirect_uri)
auth.get_app_access_token()
```

The error i receive :

```
Error: app is configured as a desktop app.
```

Ok, it doesn't work, obviously.
So, what are the correct steps to configure my app in order to use it with python?
There is an other library can I use with python?
How can I login on facebook with this approach?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short Answer: Yes you can.

follow This : http://nodotcom.org/python-facebook-tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

[facebook2](https://github.com/tino/facebook2) is a fork of [facebook-sdk](https://github.com/mobolic/facebook-sdk). My answer assumes that you are using the latter.

Facebook has documentation on how to authenticate in a desktop application at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow.

You'll need to have your desktop application use an embedded browser window to [display the Facebook login dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow#login) (you can use [the SDK's "auth_url" method](https://github.com/mobolic/facebook-sdk/blob/4f4856b91c12a13b24e62e5e48f9a487bf0c35b5/facebook/__init__.py#L460) to customize the dialog's parameters). You can then retrieve the user access token from the URL that the dialog redirects to.